# In which of the following describes the measures of all angles that are coterminal with the angle whose measure is π/6 radian?

Tags: trigonometry, angle

Got a question from Trigonometry that involves with coterminal angles.
[Pic of question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MMq9.png)

I'm a bit confused on how to determine which of the following choices are coterminal with the angle that has a measure of π/6 radian.

Your responses would be highly appreciated!!
Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Aren't two angles "coterminal" if they differ by a multiple of $2\pi$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson hello, so I tried to substitute any integers to the expression but still it didn't passed the criteria of being coterminal with measure π/6.

Comment: @GerryMyerson got any ideas if the answer is none of these or more probably c. I'm not really sure at the moment.

Comment: Well, what do you get when you take the difference between $\pi/6$ and the suggested answers? Is there one that gives multiples of $2\pi$?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please type your question rather than posting an image since images cannot be searched.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.